# how to combine these two lines of code into one

Tags: php, function

Hi I have two lines of code that call two functions on a separate page I was just wondering if I can put them together so they run at the same time at the moment only one is called when the php function is run.my code is below.

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
    {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n"; 
        include "select.class.php";
these are the lines I want to combine >>$opt->addNewMediaCrossRef($Job, $Career, $Uniq_id); 
these are the lines I want to combine >>$opt->addNewMediaRecord($Subject, $Section, $Principle, $Title, $Blurb, $Uniq_id, $Job, $Career);
    }
```

On the page I want to call the functions from

```
class SelectList
{
```

and all of my functions are here

```
}
$opt = new SelectList();
?>
```

any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: Is that really necessary?

Comment: @JohnConde yes because at the moment when I have them like this they will not run within the function they are in

Comment: I can't imagine that is due to them being on two lines. Or issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnConde at the moment the second line is being run but the first isn't any ideas why it wouldn't or a way I can put these together

Comment: @hsz what do you mean remove new line

Comment: Where does `$opt` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Template design pattern and you will be able to call all methods from different classes at once.

Comment: do you mean template method pattern ? @Oconnor